# I don't know which I to choose: "however" or "though"

Tags: however-placement

... beneficial vitamins may be, they mustn't be taken excessively.

I know I can fill in the blank with "however", but I can't understand why "though" cannot be used.

I know both are quite similar, but I guess there is a specific difference that I can't see.

Comment: done! I'm new here, thank you so much

Comment: You'd want 'though' before 'vitamins may be [very] beneficial ...'. Not here.

Comment: *Though beneficial vitamins may be,  …* doesn't make any sense.